# React Native local Notification by background service of App

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, background-service

I want to show notification when new post available in react native app.
when ever my app open it fetch latest `PostID`{`POSTID` is auto increment in online database} and save the latest `PostID` in Mobile database.

But now if App close it should check in background by fetching after every 15min about new `postID` and compare it with the saved `PostID`.
If saved `PostID` is smaller then received `PostID` then it should show notification of new post.

Comment: Are you using Expo?

Comment: No. Without Expo

Comment: You need the push notification of the native api, Have you already looked at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html ?

Comment: PushNotificationIOS is just for IOS.
I want for android also

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io), it encapsulate Local notifications feature since version 4+...

Problem: this version is only compatible with Gradle 3+, which React Native doesn't support yet (RN 0.56 still runs with gradle 2.3.3)

An alternative in the meantime is - [react-native-fcm'](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) - they're dropping development in favor of react native firebase, but has the feature you want.

You could even copy/paste the code you need if you don't want the whole 3rd party lib...